# Extracting all values between ( ) and before % sign

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

How can I extract just the number between the parentheses `()` and before `%`?

```
df <- data.frame(X = paste0('(',runif(3,0,1), '%)'))


                     X
1 (0.746698269620538%)
2 (0.104987640399486%)
3 (0.864544949028641%)
```

For instance, I would like to have a DF like this:

```
                  X
1 0.746698269620538
2 0.104987640399486
3 0.864544949028641
```

Comment: In case you just want to remove all parentheses and percent signs, you can use `gsub("[()%]", "", df$X)`

Comment: And if you're into tidyverse packages, you can use `readr::parse_number(df$X)`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match the `(` (escaped `\\` because it is metacharacter) at the start (`^`) of the string followed by 0 or more numbers (`[0-9.]*`) captured as a group (`(...)`), followed by `%` and other characters (`.*`), replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$X <- as.numeric(sub("^\\(([0-9.]*)%.*", "\\1", df$X))
```

---

If it includes also non-numeric characters then

```
sub("^\\(([^%]*)%.*", "\\1", df$X)
```

Comment: What is this sorcery?

Comment: @KaleesWaran  Will tell u if the next 5 deliveries from Swiggy are free :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `substr` since your know you need to omit the first and last two chars:

```
> df <- data.frame(X = paste0('(',runif(3,0,1), '%)'))
> df
                      X
1  (0.393457352882251%)
2 (0.0288733830675483%)
3  (0.289543839870021%)
> df$X <- as.numeric(substr(df$X, 2, nchar(as.character(df$X)) - 2))
> df
           X
1 0.39345735
2 0.02887338
3 0.28954384
```